# I don't fully understand Amps

Tags: pic, voltage-regulator, lcd, amperage

I am a hobbist in electronics, meaning I don't have any really training on electronics. Anything I know about electronics is read from books, YouTube or this site.

I am trying to design a circuit that activates a relay when a certain temperature is reached. I also want the temperature to show on an LCD. I have chosen a PIC16F877A-I/P. I have never done this before, so I am in the process of learning C machine language.

I have the circuit designed, but my biggest challenge is determining the amps that this circuit (and each component is drawing) so that I can work it out on paper, before I blow a component up. I read in the datasheets what the Max current is, but does this mean that is the current that it will draw? Does the current build up through each load? Is the end current greater then say in the middle, before a couple load (e.g. voltage regulators)?

I have attached a picture of my schematic. I may be way off. If so, please enlighten me. You will also notice that I have not finished wiring to the LCD or MCU. I am not entirely sure how to wire to the LCD I picked (NHD-C0216CZ-NSW-BBW-3V3-23858). If anyone has tips on how to wire this LCD, this would help also. It does not have the typical 7 data pins. Please help!

[image: schematic diagram]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. How did you come by this LCD without the all-important Users Guide/Programmers Guide? This is **mandatory** to have. If provided without guides surf the internet for that LCD part number. Maybe someone here knows that LCD.

Comment: How's your algebra?  Without getting into really difficult math, the first things you'll want to learn are Ohm's Law, Watt's Law, and Kirchoff's Law for something like this.  The maximum ratings on the components in some cases are the maximums that they can safely run at, and in some cases are the maximum load the device can be expected to draw, depending on what they are referring to.  In a datasheet I would expect it to be the former.  If you are sizing a power supply, you need to calculate the current in the worst case operating scenario.

Comment: The transistor base is incorrectly connected here.

Comment: I had never selected an LCD before but I am realizing I may have selected the wrong one. This is a COG LCD so I don't know if that changes things. I am challenged to figure this one out though. There is not much online regarding the model number mentioned above. I am decent at algebra and am familiar with Ohm's and Watt's Law. My problem is that I don't know the resistance of many of my components. Why doesn't the datasheet give those numbers? Also, thank you for the info regarding the transistor. I will change that. For some reason, my brain has a hard time with transistors.

Comment: @K H, What’s Watt’s Law?

Comment: To my understanding, Watt's Law is P=VI, P being Power (watts), V being Voltage and I being Current.

Answer (score 3):

1. The *ampere* is the unit we use to measure electric current. Current is the flow of charge.
2. Charge is conserved. Charge is not created or destroyed. That gives us *Kirchhoff's Current Law* (KCL). This says that in a lumped circuit (a circuit whose physical dimensions are much less than the wavelength associated with the highest frequency signals being considered), where 3 or more wires meet the total current in to the junction (aka *node*) is zero.

You can use KCL to find how the currents in your circuit add up to give you the total current required from your power supply.

Comment: +1 for ampere instead of "amp"

Comment: Kirch**h**off's …

Answer (score 1):

I see you have a transformer and a bridge rectifier, are you also building the power supply? If you are then those voltage regulator will burn and catch fire by the looks of it.

Not sure why you have 6v going to the MCU and not 5v? Use a 5v regulator like a 7805. 
You can get a 5v relay and the LM35 will run off of 5v so you can eliminate the 9v. Just to simplify everything. 
Use the 5v as the input to the 3.3v regulator. 
Don't connect your NPN transistor base to positive power because then it'll always be ON. Also it looks like you'd short it out through the MCU.

The relay coil and LCD back light will draw the most current. 
By the looks of things if you get a 5v regulator rated for 1Amp you should be good. You can calculate if you'd like to learn more about electronics.

Hope that was helpful.

Comment: The reason for the transformer and the rectifier is because this device will be wired directly into an AC circuit. The relay will turn on and off a light based on the temperature that the sensor reads. Will the regulators still catch fire if I install heat sinks?

Comment: Ah ok so you are building your own power supply. That is a project in it's self. AC is dangerous I suggest a 7v or 9v DC wall adapter. The way you have the transistor (Q) wired up it will always be on.

Comment: Thank you for the tips. I will make the changes. If I power the 3.3 V regulator with a 5 V regulator, do I need to double the capacitance of the capacitor between the two? should I be concerned with any voltage drop from the LM35 to the MCU?

Comment: Nope you do not have to double it, keep as is. There will be no voltage drop. 
just remember to fix the transistor connections as well